# FLTK choice widget with editable field

Tags: widget, fltk

FL_Choise widget allows just select an item present in drop-down. Is there any way to have combo box with editable field, i.e. which allows to specify custom value not present in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FL_Input_Choice has editable field has editable field and menu bound to button, but the drop down of FL_Choice widget is looking a way better.